# How to write 'not greater than zero' in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How should I write `not greater than 0` in VB.NET?

psuedocode:

`if x is not greater than 0 then
  do something
end if`

Comment: ok, now i see, i was always writing 'not (x > 0)' which is apparently wrong or at least convoluted, but maybe easy to read?

Answer (score 9):

If something is not greater than something, then it is less than or equal to it.  So `x <= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

if x is smaller or equal than 0 maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
if x <= 0
```

Would this not do for you? Simplest and easiest way of saying "Not greater than"

Answer (score 1):

If it's not greater than 0, it's less than or equal:

```
If x <= 0 Then
   ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

try this like

`If Not ListBox1.SelectedIndex < 0 Then`

```
      'do something
    Else
```

`do some thing
        End If`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  dim x as integer = -1

  If x < 0 OrElse x = 0 Then
        'Do something in here
  End If
```

if value of x is less than 0 or equal to 0 but not greater than 0 it will trigger the 'Do something in here

You can just change the value of the integer x from -1 to anything you want

Answer (score 0):

```
dim X as decimal

if x<0  then

end if
```